# I have an $n{\times}n$ matrix, does span{columns} = span{rows^T}?

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I need some help with that question.

I have $n{\times}n$ matrix $M$, does span{columns} = span{rows$^T$} ?

I need to prove / give a  counterexample, I think it's false but I can't find an example...

Thanks for help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: rows are u1,u2,..un and their span is {u1^T,u2^T,..un^T} and different from columns..
i dunno I just tried to find a counterexample with 3x3 matrix but can't find any, so maybe its proof?

Comment: No. Take $A= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.